# inconsistency regarding axis of rotation in equilibrium analysis

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation

If a system has no rotation, we should be able to choose any axis of rotation to do the torque equilibrium analysis. However, I found that in an non inertial system, different axis of rotation gives inconsistent results

For example, if we have a box with two pedestals placed on a block, which is moving with acceleration $a$. Assume there is enough friction between the box and the block so that there is no slipping. In order to get the maximum acceleration $a$ for which the box won't tipping over, we need to do a torque analysis.

[image]

The free body diagram will be like follow:

[image]

The right side pedestal has no $N$ and $f$ because we are calculating the critical acceleration before tipping.

Because this is the free-body diagram just before tipping over occurs, there is only translation and no rotation. We should have: $\Sigma F=ma \Rightarrow N_1=mg, and f_1=ma$ from translation, and $\Sigma\tau=0$ from rotation.

- If we use the box's center of mass as the axis of rotation, we can get the torque balance: $\Sigma\tau=-N_1\times\frac{w}{2}+f_1\times\frac{h}{2}=0$, thus we can get $a=\frac{w}{h}g$
- However, if we use the left pedestal as the axis of rotation (*which I think is more reasonable*), because both $N_1$ and $f_1$ pass the axis of rotation, we have only one term for the torque: $\Sigma\tau=mg\frac{w}{2}$, and there is no way the torque balance $\Sigma\tau=0$ can be reached.

Why is this inconsistency? Since there is no rotation movement, shouldn't we be able to choose whatever axis of rotation?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Please don't delete your own question when it's been closed only to post it again... Even if a question is closed, its comment section is still usable and you can trigger a reopen vote if you believe the vote to close was unjustified.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/723048/2451

Comment: My original post is misclassified as a homework question. It was closed and not viewable. I edited it and asked for review, but no one respond the review. 

So I rewrote the whole question following the guideline of stressing about the underlying concepts, and deleted the closed question and start a new question. 

It is marked as duplicate now.

@Qmechanic please guide how can I ask my question and not get closed?

Comment: @Y.G. there's a helpful individual in this chatroom who might be willing to help you. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies

Comment: @Y.G. don't create a new post, edit the old one to address its issues. Note that edits automatically put the post in the reopen cue, so if it stays closed is because other people though the edits didn't address the issues. Also, note that it doesn't matter whether the post is actually homework. What's important is that the post is not styled as if it was a homework question, mostly meaning it must focus on concepts, not on solving specific calculations. The clearer and easier to read you make the post, the higher the chance of it getting reopened

Comment: @MoreAnonymous. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you all for the help and guidance!